# Tweets in Python

Tags: python, search, twitter, tweets

```
def twitter_search(twitter_api,q,max_results=200,**kw):    
    search_results = twitter_api.search.tweets(q=q,count=100,**kw)
    statuses = search_results['statuses']
    max_results=min(1000,max_results)
    for _ in range(10):
        try:
            next_results = search_results['search_metadata']['next_results']
        except KeyError, e:
            break
        kwargs = dict([ kv.split('=')
                for kv in next_results[1:].split("&") ])
        search_results = twitter_api.search.tweets(**kwargs)    
        statuses += search_results['statuses']
        if len(statuses) > max_results:
            break
        return statuses


results = twitter_search(twitter_api,q,max_results=10)
print json.dumps(results[0], indent =1)
```

The last line is returning an error that `'NoneType' object has no attribute __getitem__`

Comment: Looks like `results is None`. What have you done to find out why?

Comment: I have tried reading more about the error. some are saying that results can't be indexed. I'm confused.

Comment: So you didn't, for example, `print results` to find out what it is?

Comment: Hint: if you `break` out of the `for` cycle, what will be returned?

Comment: that was the first thing I did and it returned none.

Comment: @KushalAgarwal OK, so your function is returning `None` - why didn't you say that, and what did you do to try to figure out why that is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two issues here:

1. The `return` statement is inside the for loop, and might not be reached if the loop hits one of the `break` statements first.  If it is reached, it will return earlier than you want, without running the rest of the loop iterations.
2. You are assuming `results` will have at least one element (`results[0]`).  If results is an empty list, this will fail with an IndexError.

Solution:

1. Move the `return` statement outside of the for loop (dedent one level).
2. Check `if results:` before indexing into it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is q not have trends :S

```html
q =  '#vladimirala1'  


count = 100

search_results = twitter_api.search.tweets(q=q, count =count)

statuses = search_results['statuses']


for _ in range(5):
  print "Length of statuses", len(statuses)
  try:
    next_results = search_results['search_metadata']['next_results']
  except KeyError, e: # No mas resultados si no hay mas datos
    break
  
  kwargs = dict([kv.split('=') for kv in next_results[1:].split('&') ])
  
  search_results = twitter_api.search.tweets(**kwargs)
  
  statuses += search_results['statuses']
  

print json.dumps(statuses[0], indent=1)
```